# how to get index of java list by specifying few characters not whole string?

Tags: java

```
List list = Arrays.asList("2016:6:12:6:10,"2016:6:8:1:56","2016:6:15:18:37","2016:6:2:8:20");
```

I want a index of `"2016:6:15:18:37"` from the above list by specifying  few characters i.e `"2016:6:15"`

```
 list.indexOf("2016:6:15")
```

is giving me o/p  not found (-1) which is quite expected!

How to achieve this?

Comment: You'll have to write an own method that searches the index.

Comment: Loop + String.contains?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to match by prefix, you can use `startsWith` to do this:

```
List<String> matches = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
     .filter(i -> list.get(i).startsWith("2016:6:15"))
     .mapToObj(i -> list.get(i))
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This would give you a list of strings that start in `"2016:6:15"`. If you are looking for a string that may be in the middle, use `contains` instead of `startsWith`.

Comment: Thanks a lot..Worked! :)

Comment: I'm facing one more issue...Basically my List is of List<Pair<String, String>>(Pair API is from apache commons) which has 1st argument as simple string & 2nd is date = "2016:6:12:6:10"..so the problem is when i'm searching by date & trying to get index of particular item, its giving me -1(not found)..if you can help me on this it would be fruitful for me!

Comment: @VinayThakre You should start a different question, and show the code that you have so far.

Comment: here is the link..please check.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38397547/how-to-get-index-of-listpairstring-string-pair-api-is-from-apache-commons

Comment: @VinayThakre There's no way an `indexOf` of a `String` would find anything in a list of pairs. If you understand what the code above does, you should be able to craft your own formula for getting the value by modifying the filter condition on the second line. If you are looking for indexes, not values, drop the third line, and store results in a list of integers.

Answer (score 1):

This way

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("2016:6:12:6:10", "2016:6:8:1:56", "2016:6:15:18:37", "2016:6:2:8:20");
    int index = 0;
    for (; index < list.size(); index++) {
        if (list.get(index).startsWith("2016:6:15"))
            break;
    }
    System.out.println("Index is " + index);
}
```

and output is

```
Index is 2
```

If you want to continue find all elements that start with the pattern store indices in the memory!

Comment: Is the second argument is something like 'date="016:6:12:6:10"'? If that is the case use contains() instead of startsWith()

Answer (score 0):

You can use StartsWith or contains :
starts with specifying a key

```
String key = "2016:6:15";
```

Now we use a loop to find which elements start with the provided key :

```
for (Object s : list) {
            if (s.toString().startsWith(key)) {//or contains(key);
                System.out.println(list.indexOf(s.toString()));
            }
        }
```